# how to create config file .ini

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, app-config

i want to create a config file. below are my attempts. when i run the code i get the following error

```
raise TypeError("option values must be strings")
TypeError: option values must be strings
PS M:\python lessons\flask apps\openRoutService\apps\app3>
```

please let me know how to fix it

**code**:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['USERS'] = {}
config['USERS']['NAMES']= {'AM','Thomas'}
config['USERS']['AM']['API:_KEY'] = {'5b3ce3597851110001cf62480ecf8c403567479a87de01df5da651fb'}

with open('congigs.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have got an typo in `config['USERS']['NAMES']= {'AM','Thomas'}`,
seems like it should be `{'AM': 'Thomas'}`

Comment: That's not a typo, it's a set.

Comment: @rauberdaniel I know that {'AM','Thomas'} is set, not sure that set is allowed there, but docs says:
"""Raises a TypeError for non-string values.

        The only legal non-string value if we allow valueless
        options is None, so we need to check if the value is a
        string if:
        - we do not allow valueless options, or
        - we allow valueless options but the value is not None

Answer (score 0):

as the error says, configparser can not handle object / dict values, they have to be (easily convertible to) strings. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-datatypes).

If you need to store dictionaries you have to e.g. store them as json strings instead.